# Django: ModuleNotFoundError after reinstalling Python and Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have two Django projects (project-x and project-y) which were running fine initially. However after reinstalling python and Django, I keep getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project-x'` when I run `python3 manage.py runserver` for any of my other projects.

This exact error occurs for every new project I create and try to run no matter its location and virtual environment being run. Everything was working before the reinstall and ready to ship so I am desperate to find out whats gone wrong because there is absolutely no reference to project-x in any of the other projects ..

Terminal

```
chaudim@TD project-y % python3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 68, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project-x'
```

Projects folder

```
django-projects
    - project-y
        - manage.py
        - CalendarApp
            - init.py
            - admin.py
            - views.py
            - models.py
            ... 
        - project-y
            - init.py 
            - settings.py
            - urls.py
            - wsgi.py
            - asgi.py
        
    - project-x
     same structure as above...
```

Comment: are you using the same virtual environment? What path are you on when running the runserver command? Search in your settings.py for any references to "project-x".

Comment: also, check your wsgi DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment setting

Comment: I tried different virtual environments but same error. There is also no reference to project-x anywhere in my other projects including settings, wsgi settings etc so I am beyond confused ..

Comment: can you get to a django shell?  `python manage.py shell`? if so `import os` and `os.environ.get("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE")` to see the value.

Comment: I'd look to `django/conf/__init__.py` lines 82, 69, and 170 and see what it looking for. Version of django you are using?

Comment: on linux? `grep -ir project-x *` in your django-projects folder.

Comment: check inside your `manage.py` file.

Comment: The shell is working. ```os.environ.get("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE")``` returns 'project-x.settings' which is strange because my wsgi.py is set to ```os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project-y.settings')```

Comment: I am using Django 3.1.7 Osx

Comment: what about `project-y/manage.py`? Does it set it to project-x?

Comment: that setdefault will only set it if it is not already set. try `echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in your terminal or `printenv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` (not sure what it is in macos).

Comment: I tried ```echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE``` and it returned ```project-x.settings```

Comment: Manually setting ```export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project-y.settings``` makes the server run fine without error but I am still not sure why the settings module is being set to project-x to begin with ..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables check out this to set your environment variable to the correct value.